# Python: returning length of a string

Tags: python

I have an input file that looks something like this:

```
 ADD    R0, R0, R2        
 PUTS                     

 HALT

 MSG1          .STRINGZ   "Hello Hello"
 MEMORYSPACE   .BLKW      9
 NEWLINE       .FILL      #10
 NEG48         .FILl      #-48
```

I need to return the length of the string in front of .STRINGZ (I usually don't know what that string is but this is an example.) My string has 11 characters but my code returns 17 and I can't figure out why. Can anyone help? Here's my code:

```
for line in f:
    if STRINGZ_ in line:
        string_len = 0
        stringz_ = line.split(STRINGZ_)[1]
        print (stringz_)
        string_len = len(stringz_)
        print ('len(stringz_): ' + str(string_len))
```

Comment: Strip the spaces and newlines: `stringz_ = line.split(STRINGZ_)[1].strip()`

Comment: What do you see when printing that string? Add `[`..`]` around it for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Yes!! Maybe you need remove the whitespaces

```
text = ' hello worldss      '
text = text.strip()
print len(text)
# Return 13
```

Answer (score 0):

With the code as it was posted the list that is returned by split looks like:

```
['msg1                  ', '    "Hello Hello"']
```

So you have that extra white space. Instead of adding another method to the script and striping it you can just split by '"'.

```
for line in f:
    if STRINGZ_ in line:
        string_len = 0
        stringz_ = line.split('"')[1]
```

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could edit your answer and provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.